# Automating CSS testing

Tags: php, html, css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

We are creating a web site with sharepoint 2010, the client has an existing web site developed in PHP, I am trying to test the front end as the clients want to maintain the same styling on the pages that their existing PHP web site has. for example the styling of the home link on the sharepoint site (that we are building) and the PHP site should be one and the same.

I am trying to automate the process to check the css of the php site-page to the Sharepoint Site- Page (as manually checking each and every page of the web site is very tedious job). Is there a way I can do this? I've gone through Google and I have found fizzler and sharp-query as leads to doing it (if I'm right), but couldn't go further with it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think automation would be the best way to do this job even if a tool did exist.

The HTML on Sharepoint and your PHP site would be different so performing a HTML source compare wouldn't give accurate results anyway. I don't see why you would need to check every single page anyway as most pages in Sharepoint are much the same.

I hope this offers some insight.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys, much apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Araxis Merge - http://www.araxis.com/merge/

'Merge is the visual file comparison (diff), merging and folder synchronization application from Araxis. Use it to compare and merge source code, web pages, XML and other text files with native application performance.'